# Creation a Database PostgreSQL 9.3 in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to create a database PostgreSQL 9.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've installed the database and now I'm trying to create an user, password and a new database. This is what I've done in the Ubuntu shell:

Installation

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3
```

Creation of the user "myuser"

```
sudo -u postgres createuser myuser
```

Creation of the password

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password
Enter new password: bla bla...
Enter it again: bla bla...
```

Creation of the database "newdb"

```
createdb newdb -O myuser
```

But I get this error

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: role "bla bla" does not exist
```

what can be the issue?

Comment: What is the output of this command :     `psql -U postgres -c'\du+'` ?  There is either a problem at user creation time (if you named your user `bla bla`, it should fail as there is a space in the username) or the problem is user attributes (missing login permission).

Comment: Sorry, misread your post. When you performed the change password operation, you were connected as user 'postgres' not as user 'myuser'. So that's also a problem.

Comment: Ah ok. How can I log with my new user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete  and re-create your user as follows :
`dropuser myuser`
`createuser -l myser -P`
You will be prompted for the password.
That should do the trick. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'v tried but I'v got this error: dropuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL: role "bla bla" does not exist

Comment: I guess the user was never created in the first place, just run the second command:  `createuser -l myser -P`

Comment: I enter two times the password and then I get the same error unfortunally. Instead of "myser" I typed the name of the new user "myuser" or whatever I want. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What is the output of : `psql -U postgres -c'\du+'`?

Comment: `psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Try : `psql -U postgres -W -c'\du+'`  and remember that you changed the password for user postgres when you initialy tried to set password for myuser.

Comment: first it asked me the password and then I get the same error `psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`. I'm sure, the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, verify your pg_hba.conf. 
First run :
`locate pg_hba.conf`
This should return the location of the postgresql host based authentifcation configuration file. 
Then check that the following line is set accordingly:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

This should enable passwordless access to your DB. You can try with:
`psql -U postgres`

Try it and let me know if you can connect.